# Interpreting coefficients of a dlog-dlog regression

Tags: regression

I am running a dlog-dlog (difference of logarithm*) regression and I want to convert the coefficients into marginal effects. I know that it's different from a log-log regression, in which the coefficients directly give us the elasticities.

How can we interpret the coefficients from a dlog-dlog regression?

<sub>* For example dlog (Y)= a + b dlog(X)+ error term.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Since you have differences, this means that the data is time series and we can write

$$Y_t=Y_0+\sum_{s=1}^t\Delta Y_s$$

So if the true model is

$$\Delta Y_t=\alpha+\beta \Delta X_t$$

we have

$$Y_t=Y_0+\sum_{s=1}^t(\alpha+\beta \Delta X_t)=Y_0-\beta X_0+\alpha t+\beta X_t$$

So you can say that interpretation remains the same as in model with levels.

Comment: So, is b equal to elasticity of Y with respect to X, as can be obtained from the regression "log (Y)= a + b log(X)+ error term"?

Comment: @Dlogger, $\log(Y)=a_0+a_1t+b\log(X)+\varepsilon$

Comment: @ Mpiktas, Do you also know some interpretation on Dlog - log ... ? Is that similar to the interpretation of log-log?

Answer (score 1):

If this is indeed linear then I think your underlying model may be something like

$$Y_j \approx k \, \exp(aj) X_j^b $$

where your regression does not tell you about the value of the constant $k$, but you might perhaps be able to use it to pin the first and last points of your observed data.